# Changing DisplayName of controller .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, controller

I am trying to change the DisplayName of controllers or actions in my mvc .Net Core application by using:
[DisplayName("MyName")] on the top of actions or controllers but when I discover and display them by this code:

```
_actionDescriptorCollectionProvider
                         .ActionDescriptors
                         .Items
                         .OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>()
                         .Select(a => new
                         {
                             a.DisplayName,
                             a.ControllerName,
                             a.ActionName,
                         
                         });
```

I still see the default naming like this:
"MyProject.Controllers.LoginController.Index (MyProject)"
why is this? why it has not changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `DisplayName` property doesn't respect `DisplayNameAttribute`, and I couldn't find any way to change its behavior even after looking at [TypeNameHelper](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Shared/TypeNameHelper/TypeNameHelper.cs) used by the property.

The obvious thing you can do is to use reflection

```
//using System.Reflection;
var result = _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider
    .ActionDescriptors
    .Items
    .OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>()
    .Select(a => new
    {
        DisplayName = a.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>()?.DisplayName ?? a.DisplayName,
        a.ControllerName,
        a.ActionName,

    }).ToList();
```